# Get the full exception type/message and stack trace

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x

I've written an API which returns Json in the following format...

```
{"Success": true, Result: {...}}

{"Success": false, ExceptionId: "(some uuid)"}
```

The exceptions are logged. This is fine in principle for allowing someone to discuss an error without us ever telling them what it is (as a security measure). During debugging I also want to output the error message to stop me having to refer to a database all the time.

As things stand, the problem is getting useful information from the exception (either to return or log in the db)

I'm doing something like this...

```
try:
    Ret['Result'] = <Blah>
    Ret['Success'] = True
except Exception as e:
    # ... Logging/ExceptionId
    if Settings.DebugMode: 
        Ret['Exception'] = str(e)
```

If I put a breakpoint on the last line and inspect `e` in eclipse's watch window, I get `KeyError: 'Something'`, but `str(e)` results in `'Something'` which is very unhelpful.

I've googled and I can't find any way to get a proper message from an exception. Apparently there used to be a `.message` in v<2.4 but that's no help to me in 3.3

As an alternative, I tried doing:

```
Ret['Exception'] = str(type(e)) + ": " + str(e)
```

Which resulted in `<class 'KeyError'>: 'job'` which is a little closer but it's starting to feel more and more hackish.

I also want to include a Stack Trace but have had even less luck there - I can get the `__traceback__` but of course it's not serializable and calling `str()` on it just results in a description of the object eg `<traceback object at 0x0000000004024E48>`

How can I get a decent/comprehensive error message?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You probably want `repr`:

```
Ret['Exception'] = repr(e)
```

For the traceback, use the [traceback module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/traceback.html):

```
from traceback import format_exc
Ret['Traceback'] = format_exc()
```

Comment: They both print the same thing

Comment: That's what I needed - specifically the traceback module. Many thanks